# AngularJS $scope.$watch() with two variables

Tags: angularjs, rest, web

```
scope.$watch('[apps, date]', function() {
...
...
...
}
```

Now I know that the above works, but what I need is it to display nothing unless an app is selected first and THEN after that when an app or a date is changed, the code must re-run.
Perhaps this isn't possible.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

**Context:
What happens is I get a UI grid returned with no data(as no app has been selected) until I eventually select an app.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to watch a group or a collection you just have to scroll down this page:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Search for example: `$watchGroup` inside the page